# remove bold from headings on all product pages (shopify)

Tags: html, css, shopify

I want the `h1` element on product page to be weight 300.

```
<h1>
  <strong>caption</strong>
</h1>
```

So I styled it using `font-weight: 300 !important`
(see screenshot attached : [inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqcsj.png)

But since the text I mean to style is wrapped in `<strong>`, changing the `font-weight` on the `h1` doesn't remove the bold.

It happens for all `h1` for all products.

Is it possible to overwrite the `<strong>` in all `h1` by adding a rule here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put it this way:

First: note the arrangement of your stylesheet. They overwrite eachother.
Secondly, add a new line to your css:
h1 > strong {font-weight: 300!important;}

In your attempt you're trying to change the h1 only, but you want to change this particular combination. That's what you'll do with this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

##### [Not strictly addressing Shopify here]

This solution applies in general using vanilla CSS but I'm not familiar with the `shopify` platform and I can't be sure how it's expected to be instructed and if there's a limited support for any possible nuance supported by web standards.

Since the `<strong>` tag is nested inside the `<h1>` it will hold its own style even if the parent has a lighter `font-weight`.

To address that scenario using css only, you may have a rule with a selector targeting `<h1>` descendants like this:

```css
h1 *{
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <strong>Test</strong>
</h1>
```

But there are many options.. also narrower like `h1 strong{/*...*/}`

Comment: just tried both but it says there's a syntax error ...

Comment: I'm confused. There's no reason for any syntax error in my snippet since there's no javascript. So such error is coming from your custom scenario and I have no idea what it is. Does it blame for having a selector like `h1 *`? it's perfectly valid css but I don't know how you are fitting that stuff in shopify

Comment: I should've been more precise my bad. I've added a custom css in the code.
It says "Invalid custom CSS: Only individual selectors, comma-separated lists of selectors or combiner selectors are supported. Delete it to save the changes."

Comment: if shopify was familiar to me I would be able to give you a better advice in those terms. unfortunately I don't know how it works to edit page content there, but I can assure you that both `h1 *` and `h1 strong` or even `h1 > strong` are all valid css selectors.